# Sort lines in a string

Tags: buffers, region, string

Given I have a string that maybe came from a buffer, or a clipboard, or wherever; how do I `sort-lines` in it? Given that `sort-lines` only works with a region, I assume I have to put it to a temporary buffer, but I'm not aware of a common way of dealing with such tasks.

Googling the topic doesn't give anything relevant.

Comment: I'd put it in a temporary buffer and then use `sort-lines` (if applicable) - yes. But see the Elisp manual, node [Sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html) for other sort functions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not aware of a common way of dealing with such tasks.

`with-temp-buffer` and `buffer-string` are nice general helpers here.

```el
(setq SORTED (with-temp-buffer
               (insert UNSORTED)
               (sort-lines nil (point-min) (point-max))
               (buffer-string)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible way to implement this using a temporary buffer:

```
(defun sort-string (string &optional reverse)
  "sorts an input string, using a temporary buffer"
  ;;(interactive "sto be sorted multiline string: ")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert string)
    (let ((beg (point-min))
      (end (point-max)))
      (sort-lines reverse beg end)
      (buffer-string)) ))
```

First a temprary buffer is created, then the given string is inserted, then the whole buffer is sorted, then the whole buffer is returned as a new string.

The additional parameter reverse can change the sort order.
To make this function a command, which you can call via `M-x`, uncomment the `(interactive)` line, but then you have to grab the output of the function in a useful way.

---

Evaluating following code pieces in the given order, results in the following output:

```
(setq my-string "zzzz\ndddd\nhhhhh\naaaaa")
```

> "zzzz
>   dddd
>   hhhhh
>   aaaaa"

```
(setq my-string (sort-string my-string))
```

> "aaaaa
>   dddd
>   hhhhh
>   zzzz"

```
my-string
```

> "aaaaa
>   dddd
>   hhhhh
>   zzzz"

```
(setq my-string (sort-string my-string 'reverse))
```

> "zzzz
>   hhhhh
>   dddd
>   aaaaa"

```
my-string
```

> "zzzz
>   hhhhh
>   dddd
>   aaaaa"

Comment: Upvoted -- you clearly started typing before me :)

Comment: @phils thanks, yours looks more lispy. :)